# Tar --exclude not working when popen(shell=False)

Tags: python, python-3.4, popen

I am trying to execute the following command using Popen.

```
args = ['/bin/tar', "--exclude='{}'".format('Build.tar.gz'), '-capvf', targetFile, '.' ]
popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

However the exclude part does only work if I set shell=True IE running the above command does not exclude the file 'Build.tar.gz'. 
Why is that?
Is there a way to make this work without setting the shell=True ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from `"--exclude='{}'".format(...)`, use `"--exclude={}".format(...)`

When you don't use `shell=True` you don't need to use escapes. The quotes only make sense to the shell, they are removed before the command is executed to create the list of arguments. If you use quotes in an argument list for `Popen` they are passed as literal qoute characters, so in your case you would exclude `'Build.tar.gz'` including quotes.